# Duplicate meta name="description" tag

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

Two meta descriptions in one page Issue

Hi I am trying to fix a website when i encounter something bizarre which is that there are two instances of `meta name="description"` descriptions that appear on the website pages.

This is a problem because I want the meta description I wrote in yoast SEO to only appear.

What I can assume :

One of them (I Think) is from wordpress

and the other is from Yoast SEO

I found that the meta description created by wordpress is the one I set for the website tagline

[Picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h2CF.png)

I've tried:

- Remove tagline (Leave it empty) but it would still have the two meta name="description".
- Editing the header.php file of the theme that I use ( Theme is Crane )
- Add a custom css

`.site-description { visibility: hidden; }`

Any help or insights on this would be much appreciated.